# avoiding for loops when generating lagged variables in R (and using zoo)

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I'm generating a large amount of lagged variables (365, actually) for a time series with 79,000 observations.

I currently have a column in a dataframe `OrdersData` called `prospectdrop`s.  I first convert it to `zoo` format to use the `lag()` function:

```
prospectdrops<-zoo(OrdersData$prospectdrop)
```

then I execute the for loop:

```
for (i in 1:365){
  prospectdrops[paste("lag",i,"day",sep="")] <- lag(prospectdrops,i*24,na.pad=TRUE)
}
```

then I'm forced to loop again using cbind to bind them to prepare them for data.frame()

```
for (i in 1:365){
cbind(prospectdrops, prospectdrops[paste("lag",i,"day",sep="")])
}
```

Understandably, this takes forever with the for loop function in R.  I know that "apply" could be the answer, but don't see a direct comparator in the descriptions of the functions.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`k` in `lag.zoo` can be a vector.  See `?lag.zoo`.

```
x <- zoo(11:21)
lag(x,1:3)
```

Comment: Thanks! The data is hourly, but I want the lag to be by the day (hence my 24-hour multiplier).  In the lag function, how to I have it be lag (x, 24...48....72... etc for 365 iterations? I'm again trying to avoid a for() loop.

Comment: If you wanted lag `24` and lag `48` you would just do `lag(x,c(24,48))` etc. For all 365 say `lag(x, (1:365)*24)`.